# Yfinance deployed with streamlit cloud "No timezone found, symbol may be delisted"

Tags: localhost, cloud, streamlit, yfinance

I have an app that uses yfianance to collect asset data and then run a portfolio optimization analysis.

When I run this app on **localhost** it works perfectly fine, however, when I attempt to run on **Streamlit Cloud** it gives me the following error and breaks after the user inputs have been entered.

```
1 Failed download:

- : No timezone found, symbol may be delisted
```

**I have added a requirements.txt** file with the required dependencies and versions and am unsure of how to proceed here. Has anyone encountered this error and or have any insight into how it might be solved?

[image: requirements.txt]

[image: Financial Portfolio Optimizer (CLOUD DEPLOYMENT ERRORS)]

[image: CLOUD DEPLOYMENT ERRORS]

[image: Financial Portfolio Optimizer Github Repo (LOCALHOST NO ERRORS)]

[image: (LOCALHOST NO ERRORS)]

I tried making sure the requirements.txt file specified up-to-date versions of the dependencies.

Also tried specifying the global time zone which broke the code.

[image: attempt to specify global time zone]

Comment: Could you please share a working link to your streamlit? I get an `You do not have access to this app or it does not exist` error.

Answer (score 0):

Working with timezones on *streamlit* is documented [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/timezone-handling).
The code snippet `st.global_settings.timezone = "America/New_York"` is however not valid.

You can add timezone information to the start and end date,which you pass to `yf.download()`. To change the timezone to "America/New_York" you could do:

**Example:**

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

import pytz
import streamlit as st
import yfinance as yf

tz = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
start = tz.localize(dt(2013,1,1))
end = tz.localize(dt.today())

tickers = "MA,V,AMZN,JPM,BA".split(",")
df = yf.download(tickers,start, end, auto_adjust=True)['Close']

st.table(df.head())
```

with `requirements.txt`:

```
pandas>=1.5.2
yfinance==0.2.3
streamlit==1.16.0
```

Access [app](https://karelze-streamlit-test-myapp-y5p1kv.streamlit.app/) and [code](https://github.com/KarelZe/streamlit-test).

**Output:**

[image: output]