# "No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted"

Tags: python, aws-lambda, yfinance

I'm trying to deploy a working Python 3.10 function to AWS Lambda, but I'm stuck with these yfinance (0.2.18) errors:

This call `yf.Ticker('QQQ').history(period='6mo')` generates `QQQ: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted`

While this call `yf.download('QQQ', start='2023-01-01')` generates `QQQ: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted`

Both work fine on my local windows 10.

I'm not sure if it matters, but earlier on I added `yf.set_tz_cache_location("/tmp/yfinance")` to prevent a read-only error.

I've read everything I could, but I can't find a solution. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: yf timezones can be sometimes tricky. We can add timezone information to the start and end date, which you pass to `yf.download()`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942770/yfinance-deployed-with-streamlit-cloud-no-timezone-found-symbol-may-be-deliste)